# loading a files metadata into another file using stat()

Tags: c, file, copy, stat

I am writing a program to copy a file from a source directory x to a destination directory y.

However i used stat() to get file metadata from the source file.

Is there any way i could somehow load the struct from stat() into another file so the two files share the same metadata?

Comment: You can set some values like timestamps using `utime` but don't expect any magic.

Comment: [`utime`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/utime), [`chmod`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chmod), [`chown`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/chown).  But no predefined way to set all metadata at once, or using a `struct stat` as input.

Comment: I am not sure that you don't just want to use `cp -p`.

Comment: This sounds like a [Deep Fake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deepfake) for files :)